# Can we put @postconstruct annotation in osgi service?

Tags: java, osgi, aem

I know that @postconstruct annotation is used when we want a method to call at the time of creation of its object after constructor. But my question is can we use it inside OSGI service?

Comment: Could you add your Service? Is it a Bundle service?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the dependency injection framework you use. If you use [declarative services](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html) the equivalent would be @Activate. A good example is the [enroute microservice example](https://enroute.osgi.org/examples/020-examples-microservice.html).

If you use [Aries CDI](https://github.com/apache/aries-cdi) then indeed @PostConstruct works. Unfortunately there are not yet good examples for this as it is still quite new but it works for the most part like normal CDI in Java EE.